# DefaultImagePath no longer working

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my Xamarin.Android project I have a loading image in drawable-nodpi folder.

I show this image while I'm loading other images from a url. Here's how I retrieve it;

> local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Picture; DefaultImagePath 'res:loading'

However, ever since the update to 3.5.1, the image no longer appears. I couldn't see anything that could change this in version notes.

Did the binding change somehow, or is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.